# How to find PHP Short Tag in notepad++ using RegEX

Tags: regex

I want to search the PHP short tag in notepad++ using Regular Expression.

How can i do that? Please help!

Answer (score 6):

A little enhancement to @agurchand and @NicoGranelli comments:

```
Find: <\?( )*(?!php)(?!=)(?!xml)(?!mso)
Replace: <?php
```

(The replace includes a space at the end of the statement.)

This enhancement takes care of other languages which has short_open_tags.
Also, inserts a space between the current php statement and the

Answer (score 3):

I found out the RegEx to find out the Short PHP tag.

Here it is

```
<\?(?!php)
```

Comment: `<\?(?!php)(?!=)`

is probably better, so `<?=` doesn't become `<?php=`

Answer (score 1):

You can find it without regex - just search for `<?` with whitespace after question mark.

Comment: No, you do not need regex. However regex also should looks like `<\? `